# terraform : data flow pubsubtopics to bigquery

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-dataflow, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to create pubsub topics to bigquery jobs in terraform. dataflow has this template. I did not find the terraform example. Would you provide any example terraform code ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the example you are looking for: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/dataflow_job

Comment: in the example template_gcs_path = "gs://my-bucket/templates/template_file". is this a folder or a file ? I got the below error :  Error: googleapi: Error 404: (e1efc97b8bedc6b7): Unable to open template file: gs://gcp-ent-property-ds-dev-multisource/templates/template_file., notFound
I

Comment: Paths start with "gs://" are Cloud Storage (https://cloud.google.com/storage) buckets. Here the template_gcs_path is for Dataflow templates (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/dataflow-templates). I think it should be "google_dataflow_job" for classic template. The other one, "google_dataflow_flex_template_job", is for flex template. They are two ways of building a Beam pipeline and submitting a Dataflow job as templates.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question has already been addressed, but I'd like to add my input.

Google's GCS Bucket containing provided templates for Dataflow can be found at [this link](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/dataflow-templates/latest/).

If you're looking to create a Terraform Dataflow job using the Pub/Sub to BigQuery Template, your code would look as follows:

```
resource "google_dataflow_job" "big_data_job" {
  name              = "dataflow-job"
  template_gcs_path = "gs://dataflow-templates/latest/PubSub_to_BigQuery"
  temp_gcs_location = "gs://[YOUR_BUCKER]/tmp_dir"
  parameters = {
    foo = "bar"
    baz = "qux"
  }
}
```